# Restrict activerecord-import to update only

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord-import

I'm using `activerecord-import` to bulk update a single field on existing records.

While I am learning how to use the gem. Is there a way to restrict so nothing ever gets created?

I'm currently using the `import = klass.import columns, records, on_duplicate_key_update: [:amount], validate: true` however somehow I am getting records created with blank values.

Comment: I've now added my `validates_presence_of :field_name` to restrict empty records being created however don't want to have to deal with `import.failed_instances` each batch.

Comment: Shouldn't `update_all` (https://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Relation/update_all) do that for you? You don't need to use` activerecord-import` for that purpose I guess.

Comment: You know what, I have probably had my head in the `activerecord-import` gem too many hours doing inserts... you might just have knocked me back to my senses. Will try out `update_all`!

Comment: Been there :D. Glad to help.

Comment: Can you kindly upvote the comment if it worked.